# How to use strings as type without hardcoding them?

Tags: scala, types, macros

I have some code to convert json string to objects like following:

```
def apply(line: String): PairEvent = {
    val (name, json) = line.span(_ != ' ')
    name match {
      case "OpenTabEvent" => Serialization.read[OpenTabEvent](json)
      case "CloseTabEvent" => Serialization.read[CloseTabEvent](json)
      case "ChangeContentEvent" => Serialization.read[ChangeContentEvent](json)
      case "ChangeMasterRequest" => Serialization.read[ChangeMasterRequest](json)
      case "CreateFileEvent" => Serialization.read[CreateFileEvent](json)
      case "DeleteFileEvent" => Serialization.read[DeleteFileEvent](json)
      case "CreateDirEvent" => Serialization.read[CreateDirEvent](json)
      case "DeleteDirEvent" => Serialization.read[DeleteDirEvent](json)
      case "WatchingFiles" => Serialization.read[WatchingFiles](json)
      case _ =>
        ServerLogger.info("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! unknown line from server: " + line)
        ???
    }
  }
```

You can see I hardcoded some strings and use them as types to convert to objects.

Is there any way to do the same without hardcode them? I'm not sure if it's possible, even with macro.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the class name:

```
case OpenTabEvent.getClass.getSimpleName => Serialization.read[OpenTabEvent](json)
```